# How to add text to clipboard when I open a certain firefox tab?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, clipboard

Basically whenever I open a certain site from a firefox bookmark, there is something I need to paste on that site, and its always the same thing. I can do it with a few extra clicks, but I was wondering if I could reduce the hassle somehow.

The intended behaviour would be something like a firefox addon? That whenever I open a certain site/bookmark, lets say "google.com", would fill the clipboard with a string, lets say "abc". Which I could then easily ctrl+v into the google search.

This is just an example, the actual use case is more complicated but the logic is the same.